# InvalidOperationException with XML literals vb.net

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net, xml-parsing

I am re-writing a WinForm desktop application in WPF, everything worked fine in WinForm, but I am getting an exception thrown in WPF

The part of the app that is causing issues is reading an XML file and displaying the data in textboxes, pretty basic stuff.

XML:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
> <xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
> >
>   <CORE>
>     <HEADER>
>       <name>aaabbbccc</name>
>       <region>Region25</region>
>     </HEADER>
>   </CORE>
> </xml>
> ```

VB.net:

> ```
>     Public Class MainWindow
>
>       Public filesvg As XDocument
>           Private Sub ReadHeader()
>              filesvg = XDocument.Load(LogFileName)
>              Dim mynode = filesvg...<HEADER>.First()
>              tbName.Text = mynode...<name>.Value
>              tbRegion.Text = mynode...<region>.Value
>           End Sub
>
>     End Class
> ```

when running this, the XML file is loaded correctly, but then the exception is thrown trying to create mynode.

As I said - all worked fine in WinForms, which is also a .net 4.6 app, exactly the same code.  I am using XML literals extensively throughout the code so I have to get this working again in WPF

Things I tried already:

Making it more literal: `Dim mynode = filesvg.<CORE>.<HEADER>.First()`

Using FirstOrDefault: `Dim mynode = filesvg.<CORE>.<HEADER>.FirstOrDefault()`

I must be missing something very basic. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim name As String = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "name").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim region As String = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "region").FirstOrDefault()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: yes that works.  Thanks very much, at least I am not stuck.  I was hoping though to be able to use XML literals, it is a lot tidier and easier to keep track of - plus all my WinForms code is already using literals.  Is there any reason why XML literals don't work with WPF?  I could not find any reference to that in Stackoverflow or other forums/sites.  One of the great advantages of VB.net IS (?was) the ability to use XML literals - has that been lost in WPF?  I am using Visual Studio 2015, in case that is relevant

Answer (score 0):

I just went through everything with a fine toothed comb trying to get XML literals to do their job.  I found that the problem was with the input XML file I was using.

For some reason the file had two entries for the same namespace in the header of the XML.  This caused an exception with XML literals, but jdweng's solution was more robust and could handle the double-definition of a namespace.